# Taking a ball from an urn after passing a randomly chosen ball from another urm

Tags: probability

An urn contains four blue balls and three white balls. A second urn contains five blue and four white balls. Pass up a ball from the first to the second urn and then extracted a ball second urn.

I already know how likely it is that the selected ball is white.
Real question

> If the result is blue ball, what is the probability that the first removed resulted white ball?

I know that the probability of being white in the second one is $\frac {31}{70}$.

The probability of being blue is $\frac {39}{70}$ because it is $1-\frac {31}{70}=\frac {39}{70}$. If the first is white the probability is $\frac 37$. So If the result is blue ball, the probability that the first removed resulted white ball is $\frac {39}{70}\cdot \frac 37$?

Comment: This may help:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Bayes' theorem:

- $A$... the event "the first removed ball was white"
- $B$... the event "the result is a blue ball"

all you need is the equation:

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A)}{P(B)}P(B|A)$$

You already know $P(B)$ (you already calculated it). $P(A)$ is simple. $P(B|A)$ is also not hard, it is

> The probability that a blue ball was selected from the second urn after a white ball was placed from the first to the second urn

Answer (score 1):

This is a classical problem where the total probability formula should be used. You know that a blue ball was drawn. The total probability formula tells us that the probability for drawing a blue ball is
$P(B)=P(B)\cdot P(B|B) + P(W)\cdot P(B|W)$. 
Where $P(B)=\frac{4}{7}$ is the probability to draw a blue ball, form the first urn and put it in the second urn.
$P(B|B) = \frac{6}{10}$ is the probability to draw blue ball from the second urn if you have passed a blue ball form the first urn (Blue balls become 6 in the second urn for a total of 10 balls).

Ditto for $P(W)=\frac{3}{7}$ and $P(B|W)=\frac{5}{10}$. Here the white balls in the second urn increase by one.

You are interested in the probability to have drawn a white ball from the first urn if you got a blue ball from the second urn i.e. $P(W|B)$. Here we know $P(B)$ and hence use the formula

$P(W)\cdot P(B|W) = P(B) \cdot P(W|B) $

$P(W|B)=\frac{P(W)\cdot P(B|W)}{P(B)}$

You can insert the numbers and check the result.